# Drag and Drop on a certain area like mountain unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to drag and drop an object to a particular place only like mountain. but if the user will drop the object outside the mountain it should come back to its initial position.

I already have a script on the possibility that the user will drop the object outside the mountain.. My question is that how would I be able to only drop the object specifically on the mountain only..

I tried using the OnTriggerEnter() but I don't know how to do it..

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class mountainAreaScript : MonoBehaviour {

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider){

    if(collider.gameObject.tag == "mount"){

        //Debug.Log ("working");
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider){

    if(collider.gameObject.tag == "mount"){
        //Debug.Log ("working but false");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you basically looking for this ??  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html  You'd likely just raycast "downwards" to find out "where on the mountain" you landed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the object your dragging a rigidbody. If needed set the is Kinematic to true to avoid collision issues with other objects.